# Вывод многомерного массива sql

Tags: php, sql, json, api

Имеются 3 таблицы со связью многие ко многим

(Project)-> там находятся все проекты.

(Tags)-> там находятся теги.

(P_tags)-> там находятся id проекта и id тега.

В данный момент есть такой запрос

```
$card = $Db->queryAll(
        "SELECT project.id, 
                project.name,
                project.description,
                project.image,
                project.link,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as tags 
        FROM project 
        LEFT Join p_tags ON project.id = p_tags.project_id 
        INNER join tags ON tags.id = p_tags.tag_id 
        GROUP BY project.id");
```

Возможно ли выводить многомерный массив из базы данных?
Пример вывода который должен получится

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "description": "bbb",
  "image": "",
  "link": "",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "java",
      "bg_color": 0,
      "text_color": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "python",
      "bg_color": 0,
      "text_color": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "android",
      "bg_color": 0,
      "text_color": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

В данный момент можно выводить некоторые данные только в строчку:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "image": "",
  "link": "",
  "tags": "java,kotlin,python"
}
```

PS. Вывод осуществляется через php `echo json_encode($card);`

Comment: Данные из реляционной БД будут выводиться всегда в строчку. Поэтому вы берёте цикл по полученным из БД данным и создаёте нужный вам объект как в первом варианте вручную. Советую прочитать в интернете про DTO объекты

Comment: @ArchDemon, а можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос я решил таким методом:

```
$card = $Db->queryAll(
        "SELECT project.id, project.name, project.description, project.image, project.link, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as tags 
        FROM project 
        LEFT Join p_tags ON project.id = p_tags.project_id 
        INNER join tags ON tags.id = p_tags.tag_id 
        GROUP BY project.id");

$result = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($card); $i++) { 
        $tags = explode(',', $card[$i]['tags']);
        $tags = array_chunk($tags, 3);
        $g = 0;
        $tags_name = '';
        $tags_bg_color = '';
        $tags_text_color = '';

for ($a=0; $a < sizeof($tags); $a++) { 
            $tags_name = $tags_name.' '.$tags[$a][0].',';
            $tags_bg_color = $tags_bg_color.' '.$tags[$a][1].',';
            $tags_text_color = $tags_text_color.' '.$tags[$a][2].',';
        }
        $tags_name = explode(',',substr($tags_name,0,-1));
        $tags_bg_color = explode(',',substr($tags_bg_color,0,-1));
        $tags_text_color = explode(',',substr($tags_text_color,0,-1));

        for ($b=0; $b < sizeof($tags_name); $b++) { 
            $tags_result[] = [
                'name' => $tags_name[$b],
                'bg_color' => (int)$tags_bg_color[$b],
                'text_color' => (int)$tags_text_color[$b],
            ];
        }

        $result[] = [
            'id' => $card[$i]['id'],
            'name' => $card[$i]['name'],
            'description' => $card[$i]['description'],
            'image' => $card[$i]['image'],
            'link' => $card[$i]['link'],
            'tags' => $tags_result
        ];
        $tags_result = [];
}
    echo json_encode($result);
```